# Getting error as "Source Path has too many colons " when running docker-compose up command, without specifying any path in compose file for mounting

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose, containers

Error : **the source path
"\Users\INAYGUP1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:C:\Users\
\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro"2>too many colons**

```
Dokcer-Compose.yml file: 
version: '3.4'

services:
samplewebapplication:
#image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}samplewebapplication
container_name: web
image: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0"
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: SampleWebApplication\Dockerfile
depends_on: [ mssql ]        
ports:
    - "8081:80"
mssql:
image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest"
container_name: mssql
hostname: mssql
environment:
  SA_PASSWORD: "Pass123!"
  ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
restart: unless-stopped    
ports:
  - "11433:1433"
```

I am not able to understand from where this path is being mapped . Please let me know how can I fix this  ?

Comment: Compose doesn't work with PNG files or other images, and it's hard to read and search for error messages when they're in image format.  Can you edit the question to replace these images with the actual text of the error message and the actual text of the YAML file, instead of screen shots?

Comment: I have replaced the images and snapshots with actual content @David Maze

Comment: That error message seems like it would come from a `volumes:` block in the Compose YAML.  Is that part of the file you have?

Comment: No , it is not the part of Docker-compose currently . I tried it initially but later deleted it from the docker-compose but the error still persists . Whenever I am trying "Docker-compose up" command , I am getting the stated error .

Comment: I am not sure why it is taking UserSecrets folder location . Please help me to understand that .

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue: I created docker-compose project for Windows containers, but then I wanted to change to Linux which resulted in this kind of error. Removing the project and re-adding it showed me that the error was within docker-compose.override.yml file and re-adding the docker-compose project in the Visual Studio fixed it for me.

[image: changes in git]

Comment: this was my issue as well, thank you!